# For a random permutation, what is the probability the relative order of at least 3 elements are the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Say there are $K > 3$ distinct numbers $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_{K-1}<a_K$. Under a random permutation, what is the probability the relative order of at least 3 elements are the same? Say after the permutation, these elements are labeled as $b_1, b_2, ..., b_K$. The question is what is the probability there exists $i < j < k$ such that $b_i < b_j < b_k$?

PS: Actually, my goal is to prove this probability goes to 1 as K becomes large. I realized the original problem is challenging. If there is an intuitive way to give a lower bound for this probability, it would be great.

Comment: @CalvinLin The question is not asking about three particular elements, but about the existence of three such elements.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for the clarification. Yes, the question is asking about the probability of the existence of such three elements.

Comment: Searching this probability multiplied by $K!$ on the OEIS yields that the probability is $1-\frac{(2K)!}{(K!)^2(K+1)!}=1-\frac{\binom{2K}{K}}{(K+1)!}$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla could you provide a link to the result? or could you let me know what keywords you are using for the searching? thanks.

Comment: [A056986](http://oeis.org/A056986) gives the total number of valid permutations; this divided by $K!$ would give the probability of getting a valid permutation.

Comment: I am curious.  Solving such a problem *from scratch* seems challenging.  What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @user2661923 Actually, I want to prove this probability converges to 1 as K goes large. I am working on an algorithm for large K. If there does not exist these three elements, then the algorithm will not work.

Comment: Then, what is the source of your motivation for working on an algorithm for large $K$?

Comment: @user2661923 in my algorithm, $K$ is like the number of users. It would be good enough if the algorithm only works for large population.

Comment: Yes, but what is your algorithm trying to accomplish?

Comment: See [Wikipedia page on Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics): $C_n$ is the number of permutations of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ that avoid the permutation pattern $123$ (or, alternatively, any of the other patterns of length $3$); that is, the number of permutations with no three-term increasing subsequence.

Comment: @VTand this is indeed what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the probability goes to $1$ as $K\to\infty$. Here is a way to see this:

Let's say the permutation is of $1, 2, 3, ..., K$.  The probability that $1, 2, 3$ appear in order is $\frac16$; and therefore the probability that they don't occur in order is $\frac56$. The same for the elements $4, 5, 6$. So the probability that both $1,2,3$ and $4, 5, 6$ are out of order is $\left(\frac56\right)^2$. So the probability that either $1,2,3$ or $4,5,6$ is in order is $1-\left(\frac56\right)^2$. In general, the probability that at least one of $1, 2, 3$ or $4, 5, 6$ or ... or $3t-2, 3t-1, 3t$ is in order is $1-\left(\frac56\right)^t$, which goes to $1$ as $t$ gets large.

Of course there are many other ways you could get three elements in order, so this just gives a lower bound on the probability. But this lower bound goes to $1$, and so the probability you want also goes to $1$ (even faster).